# Is it possible to Equalise the Height and Width of multiple objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Good Morning, Afternoon and Night to you

I have a design with many eclipse objects in Illustrator - all various sizes but i need to make them circles ie the same width and height.

Is there any way to select multiple eclipses and equalise the height to the width of the eclipse objects?

Comment: Please see this post, it might help.
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62187/resizing-all-objects-in-a-layer-using-illustrator-cs5

Comment: You can write a script Not a big deal but no other automatic way.

Comment: Thanks Joojaa. I suspected that was the case. Now to find someone that will write me one : )

Comment: Thanks Alex - looks like it might be something along the same lines - Have a good day ahead all

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Via a **script**.

You can download the [**"Set All Things" script**](http://js4ai.blogspot.com/2012/01/set-all-things.html) from John Wundes's blog.

Select objects, then call the script..... you can choose to set width, height, or both. Then numerically set a value for a dimension and all selected objects will be altered to match the set dimension.

I use this script repeatedly and often. It's been a life-saver.

Comment: Do you know if there is a version of this type of script that allows you to maintain the aspect ratio of each object as you change one dimension?

Comment: Not off-hand -- that's not straightforward math.. absolute value, then determine the % of change based on original value in order to to apply that % to other dimension. So, rather than simply setting a dimension to x value, a script would need to first read the *original* dimension as well. For multiple objects it could get overwhelming easily.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll have to look into it more but it sounds quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For full automation, I think you'd need a script. However it might be possible to do this semi-automatically with an Action which you could call with a Function key. I will also assume the ellipses haven't been rotated or distorted in any other way.

1. Select an ellipse using the Selection Tool <kbd>V</kbd>, and begin recording a new action. Give it a name you will remember, and set up a Function key to call the action. In the example below I'm using the <kbd>F7</kbd> key, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> enabled.

For example

[image]

2. In the tool options along the top, disable the aspect ratio link icon, and type the desired size into the Width and Height fields. In this example, I've set them to 25mm.

[image]

3. Stop recording the action.

You'll have an action that should look like this

[image]

4. Select another ellipse and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Repeat until finished.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Billy - i can use that method if doing a few but have many.

Comment: I have a script from the adobe site from DilliamWowling

Comment: function makeOvalsIntoPerfectCircles()
{
 var doc = app.activeDocument;
 var items = doc.pageItems;

 var centerPoint;

 var curItem;
 for(var x=0;x<items.length;x++)
 {
  curItem = items[x];
  centerPoint = [curItem.left + curItem.width/2,curItem.top - curItem.height/2];
  curItem.height = curItem.width;
  curItem.position = [centerPoint[0] - curItem.width/2,centerPoint[1] + curItem.height/2];
 }
}
makeOvalsIntoPerfectCircles();

Comment: @AjayAnderson - you should write an answer because it might help someone who needs something similar.  You can even choose your own answer as best. Glad you found a solution.